# How to compress 3000 images in batches of 50

Tags: command-line, tar, image-processing, compression, batch

I have a folder with over 3000 images, 
I want to compress 50 of them individually and store them in tar files.

The images are not serially named.

How to use write a bash script which does this job?

Comment: A bash script would do the job (eventually other types of solutions exist, like python). As it is difficult here to give a full course of bash programming, could you summarize your efforts and ask for more specific help?

Comment: Having read the question and written an answer I think the question is clear and shouldn't be closed as unclear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's assume your images are stored in `~/Pictures` which is shorthand for `/home/USER_ID/Pictures`. Place the following commands in your home directory in a script file called `CompressImages`. Make the file executable using:

```bash
chmod a+x ~/CompressImages
```

Call the script using:

```bash
~/CompressImages
```

Copy the following script into the file `~/CompressImages`:

```bash
#!/bin/bash

# Where to store Tars? We don't want in Images directory
COMPRESSED_DIR="$HOME/Downloads"
# TARs created with name below + "_999.tar"
TAR_NAME="CompressedImages"
# Directory Images are located in
FILES="$HOME/Pictures/*"

FileCount=50     # Number of files compressed into one Tar
TarCount=0       # Count of Tars created

i=0
for f in $FILES
do
    if [[ $(( i % FileCount )) -eq 0 ]] ; then
        let TarCount++
        TarName="$COMPRESSED_DIR/$TAR_NAME$TarCount.tar"
        tar -cvpf "$TarName" "$f"   # create .tar & add first file
    else
        tar -rvpf "$TarName" "$f"   # Add to existing tar
    fi
    let i++
done
```

---

After running `CompressImages` script check the results:

```bash
$ ll -h ~/Downloads/*.tar

-rw-rw-r-- 1 rick rick  14M Jun 18 16:55 Downloads/CompressedImages10.tar
-rw-rw-r-- 1 rick rick  48M Jun 18 16:55 Downloads/CompressedImages11.tar
-rw-rw-r-- 1 rick rick  16M Jun 18 16:55 Downloads/CompressedImages12.tar
-rw-rw-r-- 1 rick rick  55M Jun 18 16:55 Downloads/CompressedImages13.tar
-rw-rw-r-- 1 rick rick  45M Jun 18 16:55 Downloads/CompressedImages14.tar
-rw-rw-r-- 1 rick rick  43M Jun 18 16:55 Downloads/CompressedImages15.tar
-rw-rw-r-- 1 rick rick  37M Jun 18 16:55 Downloads/CompressedImages16.tar
-rw-rw-r-- 1 rick rick  38M Jun 18 16:55 Downloads/CompressedImages17.tar
-rw-rw-r-- 1 rick rick  44M Jun 18 16:55 Downloads/CompressedImages18.tar
-rw-rw-r-- 1 rick rick  47M Jun 18 16:55 Downloads/CompressedImages19.tar
-rw-rw-r-- 1 rick rick 180M Jun 18 16:55 Downloads/CompressedImages1.tar
-rw-rw-r-- 1 rick rick  53M Jun 18 16:55 Downloads/CompressedImages20.tar
-rw-rw-r-- 1 rick rick  33M Jun 18 16:55 Downloads/CompressedImages21.tar
-rw-rw-r-- 1 rick rick  13M Jun 18 16:55 Downloads/CompressedImages22.tar
-rw-rw-r-- 1 rick rick  26M Jun 18 16:55 Downloads/CompressedImages23.tar
-rw-rw-r-- 1 rick rick 1.4M Jun 18 16:55 Downloads/CompressedImages24.tar
-rw-rw-r-- 1 rick rick  13M Jun 18 16:55 Downloads/CompressedImages2.tar
-rw-rw-r-- 1 rick rick  15M Jun 18 16:55 Downloads/CompressedImages3.tar
-rw-rw-r-- 1 rick rick  23M Jun 18 16:55 Downloads/CompressedImages4.tar
-rw-rw-r-- 1 rick rick  11M Jun 18 16:55 Downloads/CompressedImages5.tar
-rw-rw-r-- 1 rick rick  12M Jun 18 16:55 Downloads/CompressedImages6.tar
-rw-rw-r-- 1 rick rick  20M Jun 18 16:55 Downloads/CompressedImages7.tar
-rw-rw-r-- 1 rick rick 7.4M Jun 18 16:55 Downloads/CompressedImages8.tar
-rw-rw-r-- 1 rick rick  21M Jun 18 16:55 Downloads/CompressedImages9.tar
```

Comment: After creating a bash file and editing the COMPRESSED_DIR, TAR_NAME and FILES variables. I encounter the following error

**user:~/catkin_ws/src$ bash CompressImages.sh

tar: $/home/user/catkin_ws/src/CompressedImages1.tar: Cannot open: No such file or directory

tar: Error is not recoverable: exiting now**

Comment: Change your variable from `$/home/user/catkin_ws/src/` to `/home/user/catkin_ws/src/`

Comment: Working Good, thank you for the Prompt reply

Comment: You're welcome. As a new user you may not know it is customary to click the grey check mark next to the answer to accept it. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can do that using `parallel -l 50`:

```bsh
cd /path/to/images

find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -print0 \
| parallel -0 -l 50 -j 1 tar cvpzf {#}.tar.gz {}
```

Add `-iname "*.jpg"` or similar to the find command if there are other files, too.

Leave out `z` option from `tar` and name it `.tar` instead of `tar.gz` if your images are already compressed (which would be the case with e.g. `jpg`).

**Explanation**:

- `find -print0` sends null-delimited data
- `parallel -0` reads null-delimited data
- `-l 50` read 50 lines for each execution
- `-j 1` executes one task in parallel, you can change it to what works best for you (depends on how many CPU Threads you have and how fast your I/O is).
- `{#}` will be replaced by the sequence number (0-n)
- `{}` wil be replaced by the 50 file names.

You can then move/rename `*.tar.gz` or `*.tar` to your liking.

This will be way faster than calling `tar` for every file adding it to an existing tar.